# Is it possible to create a file in c++ and give it attributes so that it is hidden? (On Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am writing basic code to get familiar with file handling in c++. I need to create a file to store a flag, but I want to make the file hidden. I did search on the web but did get not any concrete answers. If anyone knows how to do it, or if it is possible or not, please help.

Comment: Yes sure, that's possible. Just use the OS specific API's.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you desire to protect the contents of this file from prying or tinkering eyes? If so, this idea will only work on the naive.

Answer (score 3):

Linux doesn't really have a concept of "hidden" files, but the shell (and some other tools) conspire to pretend that filenames starting with `.` are hidden. So there are no attributes, you just have to make sure that the first character is a `.`.